# How to show that $\sup\limits_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$ is measurable for continuous $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $\delta>0$. Define for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
>   $$
> F_\delta(x):=\sup_{0<h<\delta}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}.
> $$
>   Show that $F_\delta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function.

This is essentially a "simpler" version of this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2075313/9464). Playing around with the definitions of continuous functions and measurable functions, I still don't see how to go on.

By continuity of $F$, we have (since [A continuous mapping is determined by its values on a dense set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610123/9464))
$$
F_\delta(x)=\sup_{h\in(0,\delta)\cap\mathbb{Q}}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}.
$$

Thus one can reduce the supremum over a countable set for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. But I don't see how this would help much.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447762/a-sequence-of-measurable-functions-and-the-sup-lim-sup-of-them

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Thanks for your editing.

Comment: @Max: Thanks for the link. That is exactly the direction one is supposed to think. I somehow got stuck and Davide gives the complete answer.

Comment: @Jack You are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done: since $\mathbb Q \cap (0,\delta)$ is countable, this set can be written as $\left\{q_n,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$. Consequently, 
$F_{\delta}(x)=\sup_{n\geqslant 1} g_n(x)$, where $g_n(x) :=\left(F\left(x+q_n\right)-F(x) \right)/q_n$. Now, the function $g_n$ is continuous hence measurable and [a countable supremum of measurable functions is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447762/a-sequence-of-measurable-functions-and-the-sup-lim-sup-of-them).

Comment: That was the direction I was thinking about. I had some weird thought that the sequence $\{q_n\}$ might depend on $x$ which made me stuck. Thanks for your quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Let $t_1 , t_2 , ...$ be a sequence of all rational numbers of the interval $(0, \delta ) $ and let $\Phi_n :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} ,$ $$\Phi_n (x) =\frac{F(x+t_n ) -F(x)}{t_n }.$$
The functions $\Phi_n $ are continuous and hence measurable and $$F_{\delta } (x) =\sup_n \Phi_n (x) ,$$
therefore $F_{\delta } $ is an measurable function.